# Shared Preferences is not working, android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, storage

The following method was working, but now it is not writing my integer into file.

```
public void writeChpNum(int num) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putInt("chapter", num).apply();
}
```

and this is how I get from Main class:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
chapterNum = prefs.getInt("chapter", 1);
```

Method did not work in this situation:

```
writeChpNum(1);
writeLastLine("0");

boolean deleted = file.delete();
boolean deleted2 = file2.delete();
boolean deleted3 = file3.delete();
boolean deleted4 = last.delete();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(1);
```

Here, I want to restart everything and exit, so I am removing files, but for chapters I just have to write "1"-chapter. However, it did not write.

Is this because I am exiting the app?

Comment: yes its correct how is it not working ? show some error log please.

Comment: shared pref is app private file not directly accessible outside

Comment: Yeah, I am using this method in different classes. It gets integer in MainActivity class, but it writes integer in another class. Do I have to use it in only one class?

Comment: @UmarHussain yes it is private to the app but how would that affect this situation?

Comment: @IriskulTurduev You can use that code in as many classes as you would like. I'm looking at my code for `SharedPreferences` and it looks the exact same. Mine works with no issues whatsoever

Comment: @Michael I first misunderstood the question, thaught was asking for reading the actual shared pref files,

Comment: Are you sure it is not writing the value?, and that the problem isn't you are passing the wrong value to the method?

Comment: there is no error in the code above. It is correct. Are you passing the correct values ?

Comment: Guys, I updated my question, can you look it?

Comment: Why don't  give this a try: 
`SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Comment: Does this creates default preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context object will not be available in other Activities when you access it like that. Try passing it context in method as well if you want to write this method to only one class. make method static so you don't need to create activity object.

**Edit**

Based on your new code for exiting app you need `commit()` instead of `apply()`

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

```
public static void writeChpNum(Context c, int num) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putInt("chapter", num).commit() ;
}
```

Comment: I've done both of the following (in the same app): `getContext().getSharedPreferences("sample_name", MODE_PRIVATE);` as well as `SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Sleepin", MODE_PRIVATE);` and they both work. The first is in an adapter. The second is in it's own activity.

Comment: Yeah, this method is working, however, when I want to write integer and exit the app, it did not write. The code is above.

Comment: You are exiting the app while you called apply(), use commit() method. Apply works asynchronously so while its working in background, you called exit. commit() will go to next line of code after it has done writing/failing data

Comment: @UmarHussain Thank you, you saved my life. I used commit().